# How to print one character at a time in python within an input command?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I know how to print one character at a time and the basic code I have for that is:

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.2)

delay_print("hello world")
```

But I'm making a game and I'm using delay_print for all of my code and need a way to run it within user inputs without getting this result (there is no error but I don't really want a random "None" there).

```
GetUp=input (delay_print("\nGET UP? Y/N: "))
```

And when run it displays:

```
GET UP? Y/N: NoneN
```

Which isn't exactly what I want.

So what I need is for someone to tell me how to use delay_print without the "None" appearing. Other than that it runs correctly.

Comment: I wrote it in here wrong, it's correct in my program

Comment: It prints `None` because you are passing `None` (the value returned by `delay_print`) to `input`. If you do not want that do not pass anything to `input`.

Answer (score 3):

Just brake it into two  lines and leave `input()` without a prompt:

```
delay_print("\nGET UP? Y/N: ")
GetUp = input()
```

That way, your `print` will behave the way you want it and the `input` will read the user input unobstructed.

Do not complicate your life when you don't have to ;)

---

If you insist on doing it in a single line you have to modify the definition of `delay_print` by adding a `return ''` statement. That way, instead of the default `None` it will return and empty string instead.

Note however, that `GetUp=input(delay_print("\nGET UP? Y/N: "))` is not a *very clean* coding style. In my opinion that is.

Answer (score 1):

You can return `""` from `delay_print`, so `input(delay_print("whatever"))` will print slowly, then print an empty input prompt at the end of the line, which seems to be what you want.

The current behavior happens because `delay_print` returns `None`, and that is printed by `input` as a prompt.

Comment: That will result in a newline after the printed text since `input` function adds one if the prompt is provided.

Comment: @no1 Really? I've tested and this works fine for me.

Comment: Oh, my eyes made mistake. "...written to standard output **without** a trailing newline"

Answer (score 0):

The *None* appeared because delay_print was returning no values.

```
import time
import sys

def delay_print(s):
    for c in s:
        if c:
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.50)
    return ''

#delay_print("hello world")

GetUp=input(delay_print("\nGET UP? Y/N: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

See [built-in function input](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#input):

> If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline.

You gave an argument (`delay_print("\nGET UP? Y/N: ")`) to it (as prompt). So, the interpreter first evaluates the argument. At this time, the program does the write, flush and sleep. Then it returns `None` (implied when running to the end of a function). That was then provided as the prompt of `input()`.

Your code works like this one:

```
temp = delay_print("\nGET UP? Y/N: ")
# assert temp is None
GetUp = input(temp)
# Same as input(None)
```

So, that is the mistake.

The correct should be:

```
delay_print("\nGET UP? Y/N: ")
GetUp = input()
```